# Convertir un metodo http de tipo get para que se ejecute de forma sincrona en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estoy tratando de convertir una funciòn de peticiòn HTTP GET para que se ejecute y hasta que no se resuelva lo que se encuentra dentro no avance. dentro me suscribo, recibo los datos y los asigno a un objeto(**data**) que se encuentra al inicio, sin embargo se ejecuta el console.log(**data**) primero el cual no me mostrara nada(ya que cree el objeto vacio), estuve investigando e intente usar asyn & await pero no tuve exito, lo ideal seria que cuando **data** tuviera los datos que le asigno dentro del subscribe hay si se ejecutara el console.log(**data**) , a futuro el return que se encuentra comentado devolvera **data**
Gracias. C:

```
autenticated() {

    const authData = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      })
    };

    let data = {

    };

    this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiUser}`, authData).subscribe(resp => {
      this.data = { ...resp, status: true };
      console.log(this.data = { ...resp, status: true })
    }, error => data = { status: false });


    console.log(data);

    /* return data; */
  }
```

Comment: Por la naturaleza del llamado, sería mejor preparar el front para que soporto la ausencia de datos hasta que el get los reciba. Habiendo dicho esto, pueden existir casos que requieran esperar, podrías describir mas la situación, por ahí la solución puede ser otra que se ajuste mas a tus necesidades.

Comment: La idea en general es poder validar el acceso a cada dirección que tenga mi pagina con Guard(CanActive) entonces cuando el usuario inicie sesion guardare el token en localStorage, luego cuando quiera acceder a una dirección ej: panels,home... can Active haga una validación con ese token la cual es: hacer una petición HTTP get donde envió el token y si me trae información del usuario sea true y pueda acceder de lo contrario sera redirigido a  login, es asi como yo lo pense para validar que el token sea verdadero, no se si sea una buena practica o este haciendo una locura.

Comment: No se si es una locura, pero por ahí, podrías traer todas las rutas válidas para ese perfil en un solo pedido (al momento de hacer login), y después tenerlas en el front y compararlas, para evitar pedidos al back con cada cambio de ruta. Además de validar que la ruta esté permitida, en cada consulta, podrías validar el token también o la respuesta del back.

Answer (score 0):

como mencionas, son llamadas asíncronas, lo que puedes hacer es colocar el `console.log(data)` dentro del subscribe para que funcione. Para el futuro puedes regresar la llamada al servicio `this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiUser}`, authData)` y cuando se implemente, subscribirte a la respuesta, pero en otra función. Ejemplo:

```
autenticated() {

    const authData = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      })
    };

    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiUser}`, authData)
}

autenticated().subscribe(resp => {
    this.data = { ...resp, status: true };
    // código cuando la respuesta es exitosa
}, error => data = { status: false });
```